# Show that $(a_1,a_2/2,a_3/3,a_4/4,\ldots)$ is not dense in $\ell_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $T\colon \ell_\infty \rightarrow \ell_\infty : (a_1,a_2,\ldots) \mapsto (a_1,a_2/2,a_3/3,a_4/4,\ldots) $.

Show that $\operatorname{range}(T)$ is not dense in $\ell_\infty$.
I want to ask for a hint or a solution to this problem.

Comment: Hint: If $(x_n)$ is in the range of $T$, then $x_n\rightarrow 0$. Can the sequence $(1,1,\ldots)\in\ell_\infty$ be the limit in norm of a sequence of such $(x_n)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $(x_n)$ is in the range of $T$, then $x_n\rightarrow 0$. What is a lower bound of the distance in $\ell_\infty$ from the vector $(1,1,\ldots)\in\ell_\infty$  to such an $(x_n)$?